# How to provide internet to MacOS, through an ethernet cable connected to Ubuntu ,

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, mac

I have a macbook macOS catalina and ubuntu 22.04 machines next to each other.

Ubuntu machine is getting good internet due to better wifi card reception. While macOS is not getting decent WIFI signals, so poor internet.

Can I connect an Ethernet cable from mac to Ubuntu machine and get internet from Ubuntu on my macOS machine.

Please help.